# Listing which files Terminal opens at load time

Tags: linux, macos, terminal

When I open Terminal I would like to know which files are being loaded (e.g .bashrc, .bash_profile etc).  Although I'm doing this in OSX, I guess it's also relevant to logging in via SSH to a Linux server.

Is there any way I can log this out or to check the files loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [fs_usage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/fs_usage.1.html) tool, which "*presents an ongoing display of system call usage information pertaining to filesystem activity*".

Alternatively, the [opensnoop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/opensnoop.1m.html) tool which, as the description states "*tracks  file opens. As a process issues a file open, details such as UID, PID and pathname are printed out*"